# How to return a view using ASP.NET Core API controller

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, view

I am using ASP.NET core, which I have read has the controller and API merged as one. I have successfully managed to get the JSON data to work, however, the view is not working. It just says the page can not be found. I am able to view the home page, however, this is created as an MVC controller and not as an API controller.

```cs
namespace ScheduleWebApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StaffHoursWorkedController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this?  API controllers are not meant to return Views. If you want to return a View, use a regular Controller

Comment: I thought MVC Controller and Web API had merged together in .netcore. I assumed that you can get views and data now from the same controller rather than having a separate controller and a separate web API like you do in .net framework.

Comment: Yes, they now both inherit from the same ControllerBase class now, but the controller class behaves differently depending on the presence of the `[ApiController]` attribute.   All it means is that you don't have to import and configure two separate Controller types in your project.  If you want to mix the controller action types, you need to remove the `[ApiController]` attribute, but then you lose some of the extra features for api like auto content negotiation.  Best not to mix the two in the same controller, as it tends to be a violation of separation-of-concerns.

Comment: What do you mean the page not found? Share us a screen shot about your request and result.

Answer (score 7):

For MVC Controller, its base class is `Controller` which is a base class for an MVC controller with view support.

For API Controller, its base class is `ControllerBase` which is a base class for an MVC controller without view support.

Follow steps below:

1. Controller

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : Controller //ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<ValuesController> _logger;
    public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }        
}
```

2. Right click `View()` -> Add View
3. Access `Index` page with `https://localhost:5001/api/values/index`